# Optimizing 1-0 Knapsack problem to maximize weight instead of value

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode, knapsack-problem

I want to know how to approach the following problem: given a limited amount of people allowed on a bus (not exceeding 100) and the following data: group name, amount of members in the group, their luggage weights. I have to make use of dynamic programming, to calculate the most profitable way to pack the busses. The profit is obtained by multiplying the weight of the luggage by $5.

To my understanding, majority of the resources online cater for maximizing the value-field, however I need to maximize profit, and thus maximize the weight of the luggage, while just keeping in mind the constraint of having only 100 people on the bus. (there are 5 busses in total, so would reiterate 5 times)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I have only created a group object, and am busy deciding if it would be more efficient to use an List, or matrix in order to evaluate the most profitable way to arrange the groups. (using Java, but basic pseudocode/algorithm analysis would suffice)

Comment: Just swap weight and value.

Comment: Why is your problem different from the knapsack problem ? values corresponds to the profit of the luggage of a group(so sum luggage weight x $5) and weights corresponds to the number of people in a group.

Comment: sorry for only responding now, I also thought I would just swop them around. Do you maybe have any helpful links to help me visualize the problem, or see sample code preferably?